# Rails 5 JSON_API serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, json-api

I have the following model:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

  # Associations
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  belongs_to :team_leader, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I am using the **active_model_serializers** version **0.10.6**

Here is the code in my serializer:

```
class TeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :can_delete, :can_edit

  has_many :projects
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :team_leader
end
```

Here is the result of the serialization:

```
{  
 "data":[  
    {  
       "id":"1",
       "type":"teams",
       "attributes":{  
          "name":"OA",
          "can-delete":true,
          "can-edit":true
       },
       "relationships":{  
          "projects":{  
             "data":[  
                {  
                   "id":"2",
                   "type":"projects"
                }
             ]
          },
          "users":{  
             "data":[  
                {  
                   "id":"25",
                   "type":"users"
                }
             ]
          },
          "team-leader":{  
             "data":{  
                "id":"25",
                "type":"team-leaders"
             }
          }
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem I have is with the "team_leader" relationship, as I expected it to be of type "user" , but it is not. It is of type **team-leaders**, but I have no model team leader and this creates a confusion in my front-end application ( which is an ember 2.14 application ). Is there a way to override the **type** only for a relationship, for a serializer? if not, I am open to any suggestions in order to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class TeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :can_delete, :can_edit

  has_many :projects
  has_many :users

  attribute :team_leader do
    team_leader = object.team_leader
    UserSerializer.new(team_leader) if team_leader
  end
end
```

This implies existence of `UserSerializer` of course, but it may be very simple, for example:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :foo, :bar, :etc
end
```

Comment: Not working. With your suggestion it adds the attribute to the team, but not to the relationships of the team ( as it should in a json-api response ).. Thank you though :)